# Are there dtrace ustack() helpers on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, opensolaris, dtrace

I've been wondering if there is any chance to use dtrace ustack helpers on Mac OS X for python and other interpreted languages? I know that you can figure out what python and php on OpenSolaris are doing when giving the ustack some extra memory for a buffer. Is this somehow possible on Mac OS X?

Regards
raichoo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the ustack helpers are broken on MacOSX:

http://opensolaris.org/jive/thread.jspa?threadID=138082

Edit: the opensolaris links have been decommissioned.  Here's another copy:
http://www.mail-archive.com/dtrace-discuss@opensolaris.org/msg04668.html

Edit 2: The best way (I know of) to change this is to escalate with your Apple developer liason (if you have one) or file a bug at bugreport.apple.com.